# Trying to find the most connected node in cypher

Tags: neo4j

I'm using NEO4J 2.0 M6 and I'm trying to find the most connected nodes and list order them by their connections descending. I have tried many snippets from lots of other posts but without success.

The data I have is simple:

```
create (Account1 { id:123}),
    (Account2 { id:456}),
    (Account3 { id:789}),
    (Account4 { id:101}),
    (PERMISSION1 { name: 'ChangeOneThing'}),
    (PERMISSION2 { name: 'ChangeAnotherThing'}),
    (PERMISSION3 { name: 'ConsumeThePlanet'}),
    (Account1)-[:ADDED]->(PERMISSION1),
    (Account1)-[:ADDED]->(PERMISSION2),
    (Account2)-[:ADDED]->(PERMISSION2),
    (Account4)-[:ADDED]->(PERMISSION2),
    (Account3)-[:REMOVED]->(PERMISSION3)
```

What I need as the result is something like the following as I am trying to determine which are the most added permissions in order to creating groupings in a new system.

```
PermissionName       Count
==========================
ChangeAnotherThing   3
ChangeOneThing       1
```

This will allow me to determine the most popular groups of permissions that have been assigned to accounts which will help me to simplify the current infinitely custom allocations into small groups.

I'm very new to cypher and here is my attempt at getting it to work:

```
match (account)-[:ADDED]->(permission)<-[:ADDED]-(other_account)
return count(permission) asscore, collect(permission.name) as permissions
order by score desc
```

But that just gives me:

```
6     ChangeAnotherThing, ChangeAnotherThing, ChangeAnotherThing, ChangeAnotherThing, ChangeAnotherThing, ChangeAnotherThing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you want something like: take each permission, find all accounts that have added it and count them to see how many times the permission is used. The easiest way to do this is probably to label your accounts and permissions when you create the graph, for instance

```
CREATE (acct1:Account {id:123}), (acct2:Account {id:456}), 
    (acct3:Account {id:789}), (acct4:Account {id:101}),
    (perm1:Permission {name:'ChangeOneThing'}),
    (perm2:Permission {name:'ChangeAnotherThing'}),
    (perm3:Permission {name:'ConsumeThePlanet'}),
    (acct1)-[:ADDED]->(perm1), (acct1)-[:ADDED]->(perm2),
    (acct2)-[:ADDED]->(perm2), (acct4)-[:ADDED]->(perm2),
    (acct3)-[:REMOVED]->(perm3)
```

and then query it like this

```
MATCH (permission:Permission)<-[:ADDED]-(account:Account) 
RETURN permission.name, COUNT(account) AS score 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

You don't have to count or group the permissions, when you return `a, count(b)` a becomes a grouping key–you get one row for each a and the aggregate value of b.